# How to get data from firebase as json with java jsp or servlet

Tags: java, ios, rest, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've looked over the Firebase documentation for their REST api: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start and also for their documentation with AdminSDK: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start

I'm need to make an iOS app that calls a GET to a java backend script that retrieves data from Firebase's Realtime Database (preferably as a JSON), and I'm having trouble figuring out how to do it. The app itself is developed in Swift and I can get the database read and write with that, but it needs to be in Java and all the documentation seems to be for Android development.

My idea was to make a jsp or servlet on the computer that's running the iOS code that receives the GET from the iOS app and then runs the java RESTful APIs to get the data as a JSON and send it back to the iOS app.

Any idea how to tackle this problem?

Edit: here's my code!

This is my java class that is supposed to be the server that the app will do a get request to:

```
public class AdminSDKInit {
    FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("/*this is my json key*/");

    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
        .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
        .setDatabaseUrl("/*the url to my database is here*/")
        .build();

    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

}
```

this is the dependencies bit of my gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    // This dependency is exported to consumers, that is to say found on their compile classpath.
    api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'

    // This dependency is used internally, and not exposed to consumers on their own compile classpath.
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:21.0'

    // Use JUnit test framework
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    //Firebase Admin SDK
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:5.9.0'
}
```

Edit2: 
[Here's what the console outputs as an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1jUg.png)

On top of this,It says that the imports for the [java wrapper for the SDK](https://github.com/bane73/firebase4j) can't be resolved, [here's the image of them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5CYo.png)

Comment: The Admin SDK is specifically for use in JVM code, not for use in Android. You can use it in your Servlet/JSP container. But why on earth do you want to wrap the Realtime Database in a servlet, when it has a perfectly good iOS SDK already?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen 
Its a requirement of the program we are building. We can't do our backend calls in swift and must use Java for backend work -- which is mainly the RESTful APIs. I'm not sure how to use the Admin SDK in this context.

Comment: You add the Admin SDK to the dependencies of your app, and then use it in the Servlet. What specific step are you stuck on?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I've made a Gradle project in eclipse and have added the dependency but it is not compiling and I'm still receiving errors on building. The errors are that the Firebase stuff isn't declared (i.e. that I haven't added the dependency). I'll update the post with my code!

Comment: Hmm.... that gradle looks similar to what I'd expect. Please edit your question to include the exact error message. Maybe somebody else recognizes it.